# How to call R's Image function from C++

Tags: c++, r

How can I call R's **image** function from C++?

For example:
image(x = M , col = grey(seq(0, 0.7, length = 1000)), axes = FALSE)

where M is a 100x100 matrix in c++.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) which lets you embed R inside of C++ applications.

There are several directories with examples, and plotting is among them.